How can I plot indicator values in data window
How can I plot lres and lsup values that are in if statement in data window in this pinescript code:
if barstate.islast
        lres = line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=lvalue, x2=lindex, y2=lvalue, color=isBullish ? bearishColor : bullishColor, width=2, style=line.style_dashed, extend=extend.left)
        lsup = line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=llvalue, x2=llindex, y2=llvalue, color=isBullish ? bullishColor : bearishColor, width=2, style=line.style_dashed, extend=extend.left)
        lsup

Iam new to pinescript, please help this nooby :)
I've asked ChatGPT about this, unfortunately, it was a not good in pinescript, now the only way for me is stack overflow

lres and lsup are just lines. Their values are lvalue and llvalue respectively.
So, just do
plotchar(lvalue, "lvalue", "", display=display.data_window)
plotchar(llvalue, "llvalue", "", display=display.data_window)


where to keep this code, it tells me: Cannot use 'plotchar' in local scope

You need to put it in the global scope. Outside of any if blocks.

and also:
Undeclared identifier 'display.data_window';

If this is v4, try data_window only.

i again converted it into v5, can you please please please provide me full code, as a exchange of reputation
